# How Do You Make Your Sheep Different Colors On Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I look all over the web to find how to do it, but all there is are videos on YouTube... And the thing that sucks is my school gave us iPads but they blocked YouTube so I have no way to view them. So how do I get colored sheep?

Answer (score 6):

Right click the sheep with the corresponding dye in your hand.

Comment: A list of corresponding dyes and how to craft them can be found here-->http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Crafting/Dye

Comment: I'm very sure he/she is talking about the Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct items for dyeing sheep then all you do is tap on the sheep with the dye in your hand and it will instantly change to the allocated colour (its babies will also be that colour.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in creative, simply find the dye in your inventory and put it in your hand. Then, all you have to do is hold down on them like you would hold down on a block when you want to destroy it. In survival, the same rules apply but you must make the dye first. You can dye both adult and baby sheep, and the baby will grow up into the color you died it. If you use the sheer and shave a sheep while it is died, you will get that color wool. (Ex: shave a pure sheep to get purple wool.) They will grow back white. It is possible to dye them back to white.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you have two adult sheep that are different colors (Red/Blue, White/Red etc) and you breed them, their babies will be a mix of those colors.

However, I have tried mixing Cyan and Pink, but their babies were either Cyan or pink. I believe the 'mixing' will only work with primary colors. (i.e. not Cyan and pink etc)

Answer (score 0):

You make the color of dye you want to use (Dye crafting recipes are [here](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Dye)) and **hold down** on the sheep with the dye in your hand.

Ta da!

Answer (score 0):

There should be guides on how to craft each dye in survival on the Minecraft Wiki, so when you get the dye, all you need to do is hold the Right Mouse and Ta-da! You have a colorful sheep!
And if your in creative, all you have to do is get the dye out and right click.